# LineageOS Recovery command line interface?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, lineageos, shell

Is there an adb shell command line interface for LineageOS recovery? Alternatively, which adb commands will work when booted into lineage recovery? I want to factory reset my device as part of an install script running on my desktop, and I can't find any documentation about which commands (if any) are supported. The only command I can find is a fastboot command; `fastboot erase <partition>`, however I would prefer to do it from recovery. My old device had TWRP recovery and that did have a command line interface which could be used from a shell running on the device.

Comment: is adb shell root?

Comment: @alecxs It can be yes!

Answer (score 1):

you can always use core utils

```
find /dev/block -iname userdata
blkid /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata
mkf2fs /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata
```

mkf2fs is for f2fs
mke2fs is for ext4